# Code to generate pages of boxes filled with user/pass not wrapping and gets too tall

Tags: python, reportlab

I want to change this code so that it wraps the table in each page as much as possible to avoid printing out too many papers.
For example, generating 256 users gives me 14 pages to print, *too much paper waste over time*.

> PS: you are welcome to change the table style.

**The below is the code:**

```
import random
import string
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, Spacer
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.platypus import TableStyle
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import portrait, A4

# Function to generate random passwords based on the selected format
def generate_password(format):
    if format == '1':
        return username
    elif format == '2':
        return ''.join(random.choice(characters) for _ in range(3))
    elif format == '3':
        return ''.join(random.choice(characters) for _ in range(4))
    elif format == '4':
        return ''.join(random.choice(characters) for _ in range(5))
    else:
        return ''

print(
    """
=====================================
HOTSPOT TICKET GENERATOR FOR MIKROTIK
=====================================
BY ALI

"""
)

print("Enter the number of users: ")
numOfUsers = int(input())

print("Enter the rate limit [Up/Down] (ex: 1M/2M):")
rateLimit = input(str())

print("Enter username format (ex: user_, user-..): ")
usernameFormat = input(str())

print("Enter password format (1 for pass=user, 2 for 3-chars, 3 for 4-chars, 4 for 5-chars): ")
passwordFormat = input()

print("Enter limit uptime (ex: 1d, 1h, 1m): ")
limitUpTime = input(str())

print("Enter limit bytes total (ex: 1K, 1M, 1G): ")
limitBytesTotal = input(str())

characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits

# Create a list to store usernames and passwords
usernames_passwords = []

# Generate usernames and passwords
for i in range(1, numOfUsers + 1):
    username = usernameFormat + str(i)
    password = generate_password(passwordFormat)
    usernames_passwords.append((username, password))

# Create a PDF document
doc = SimpleDocTemplate("usernames_and_passwords.pdf", pagesize=portrait(A4))

# Create a list to store content
story = []

# Create a table for displaying usernames and passwords
table_data = []

for username, password in usernames_passwords:
    table_data.append([f"Username: {username}", f"Password: {password}"])
    table_data.append([Spacer(1, 10)])  # Add 10-pixel space between rows

# Define table style
table_style = TableStyle([
    ('BACKGROUND', (0, 0), (-1, 0), colors.beige),  # Header row background color
    ('TEXTCOLOR', (0, 0), (-1, 0), colors.black),  # Header text color
    ('ALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'CENTER'),  # Center text horizontally
    ('FONTNAME', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 'Helvetica'),  # Header font
    ('BACKGROUND', (0, 1), (-1, -1), colors.beige),  # Data rows background color
    ('LEFTPADDING', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0),
    ('GRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 1, colors.black)  # Border for data rows
])

# Create a table and apply the style
table = Table(table_data)
table.setStyle(table_style)

# Add the table to the story
story.append(table)

# Build the PDF document
doc.build(story)

print("PDF generated successfully.")
```

This is what I'm getting (for more clarification):

[image: ...]

And this is what I want it to look like if you understand, fit as many as possible in each page so i get to print less pages than usual
(PS: No need to show ''member-free'' and the numbering ''1, 2, 3...'', just each user and pass in a box with little white space/padding around so I can cut them out later on.)

[image: ...]

Comment: So, are you saying you want this to be in multiple COLUMNS?  Reportlab can't do that automatically, although it's not hard to track that yourself.

Comment: I just want each [user+pass] in a box to go horizontally, not vertically. i got it to make a small 3px space between each row, but i want it next to each other, for example each row has 2 or 3 [user+pass] boxes, not  row under row starting from the middle top. im getting 256 users take 10 pages, trying to make it fit in less pages. I need help, change the code or use other libraries or whatever, im out of ideas

Comment: That's not hard at all, but you can't use a Reportlab table to do it.  Just write a function that prints one box gives the username and password, then call it repeatedly.  Check out my gist, which produces Avery mailing labels in a very similar way.  https://gist.github.com/timrprobocom/3946aca8ab75df8267bbf892a427a1b7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what you want.  You might consider passing your input data as command-line parameters instead of inputs.  That makes it a lot easier to run several in a row.

Also, `input(str())` is not what you want.  The parameter to `input` is the prompt to use.

```
import random
import string
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import portrait, A4

# Function to generate random passwords based on the selected format
def generate_password(format):
    if format == '1':
        return username
    else:
        return ''.join(random.choice(characters) for _ in range(int(format)+1))

print( """
=====================================
HOTSPOT TICKET GENERATOR FOR MIKROTIK
=====================================
BY ALI

"""
)

#numOfUsers = int(input("Enter the number of users: "))
#
#rateLimit = input("Enter the rate limit [Up/Down] (ex: 1M/2M): ")
#
#usernameFormat = input("Enter username format (ex: user_, user-..): ")
#
#passwordFormat = input("Enter password format (1 for pass=user, 2 for 3-chars, 3 for 4-chars, 4 for 5-chars): ")
#
#limitUpTime = input("Enter limit uptime (ex: 1d, 1h, 1m): ")
#
#limitBytesTotal = input("Enter limit bytes total (ex: 1K, 1M, 1G): ")


numOfUsers = 128
usernameFormat = 'user'
passwordFormat = '4'

# A box is 1.5" by 5/8".
# We have 1/2" margin on all sides, leaving 4 boxes across.

PAGE = portrait(A4)
MARGIN = 36
BOXW = 1.5 * inch
BOXH = 5 * inch / 8
ACROSS = (PAGE[0] - 2*MARGIN) // BOXW
DOWN = (PAGE[1] - 2*MARGIN) // BOXH - 1

def setup(doc):
    doc.setLineWidth( 0.5 )
    doc.setFont( 'Helvetica', 9 )

def createLabel( doc, x, y, ord, user, password ):
   doc.setStrokeColor( (0,0,0) )
   doc.rect( x, y-BOXH, BOXW, BOXH )
   doc.line( x, y-12, x+BOXW, y-12 )
   doc.setFillColor( (0,0,0) )
   doc.drawString( x+3, y-9, "member-free" )
   doc.drawRightString( x+BOXW-3, y-9, str(ord) )
   doc.drawString( x+3, y-24, "Username:" )
   doc.drawString( x+3, y-36, "Password:" )
   doc.setFillColor( colors.purple )
   doc.drawString( x+69, y-24, user )
   doc.drawString( x+69, y-36, password )

def coords(n):
   x = MARGIN + (BOXW+3)*(n % ACROSS)
   y = PAGE[1] - MARGIN - (BOXH+3)*((n // ACROSS) % DOWN)
   return x,y

characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits

# Create a PDF document
doc = canvas.Canvas("usernames_and_passwords.pdf", pagesize=PAGE)
setup(doc)

# Generate usernames and passwords
for i in range(numOfUsers):
    # Have we started a new page?
    if i and not i % (ACROSS*DOWN):
        doc.showPage()
        setup(doc)
    username = usernameFormat + str(i+1)
    password = generate_password(passwordFormat)
    x,y = coords(i)
    createLabel( doc, x, y, i+1, username, password )


doc.save()

print("PDF generated successfully.")
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: I love you, this is perfect. just one tiny question: Im modifying it to print at max 256 users on 4 pages, each page 64 users, but its printing it all in 1 page, so anything after 68 doesnt show.

Comment: Isn't that something you can fix?  It's not all that tricky, similar to the code that's already there.

Comment: I know, im trying my best to fix it myself. I dont really know much about coding, a beginner, I just try anything; edit, undo, edit, undo.

Comment: Did you notice I fixed it?

Comment: Yes I did, thank you again. i did comment it yesterday for some reason it disappeared.